# Domain Port uWsgi Tutorial - uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#about-the-domain-and-port

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Am following the Tutorial here - as i was tinkering with my working Nginx config and messed things up . Now i have a very basic doubt . In the uWsgi docs here - https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#about-the-domain-and-port

Its mentioned that -

*This should serve a ‘hello world’ message directly to the browser on port 8000. Visit:*

> http://example.com:8000

I substitute my own domain / FQDN , here --

> http://digitalcognition.co.in:8000

zilch - nothing ? 
My question - having gone through the tute till this stage , how does anything know yet whats my domain - i havent configured Nginx yet ? Total confusion. Someone kindly help thanks .

Further - my uWsgi code line in the terminal , within a Conda env -

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file dc_dash_proj/wsgi.py
```

I do understand that the test.py file that they would want us to create -i have skipped and gone directly to my django project wsgi.py file , but then the doubt is the same - how will my domain or my FQDN as they call it be known to the system or some code within uWsgi?

Comment: screen grab from the tutorial - here - https://datasciencewithrandpython.blogspot.com/2019/09/domain-port-uwsgi-tutorial-uwsgi-docs.html

Comment: I presume it would be ok - to refer to the Domain on FQDN in this manner if lets say for Django - the Domain or FQDN was coded into the ALLOWED HOSTS in settings.py - but that seems to be left as a presumption here . Needs to be explicit. In development i would use - ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] . Thus needs further clarification asto how it shall pick my DOMAIn name if i dont have a ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] ??